# UIKeyboardWillShow/WillHide Notification, how to know when those notifications are for the regiestered observer

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a `UIView` subclass with an added observer for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. This `UIView` is in a `UITableViewCell` subclass. I have two other `UITableViewCell` subclasses that contain `UITextFields`. When those text fields are tapped, my custom `UIView` receives those notifications. I have these three `UITableViewCell` subclasses setup for a email composer view type of thing.

How can I make sure that when my `UIView` subclass receives the keyboard will show or hide notification that it is for the `UIView` and not to the other `UITableViewCell's` that contain ui text fields?

I should mention that I have a UIWebView in my UIView subclass. When a contenteditable div is tapped, I want to receive notification that the keyboard came up but only for my UIWebView instance.

I was thinking I could do the following, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector@(selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:_webView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends for what you need the `UIKeyboardNotification`, you can achieve the same thing with:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

To see when the editing did begin. And this to see when the editing did end:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Don't forget your `UITableViewCells` must comply with the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

[Quick reference about the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

---

**Edit:** One more thing, the solution I gave you makes sense when you have the need to know when a specific `UITextField` became first responder. If you don't care about that, and you just need to know when the keyboard actually comes and goes, you should notify the `UIViewController` that have your `UITableView` instead of each individual cell. The `UIViewController` should then take the proper action.

Comment: What about when I have a UIWebView in a UIView subclass? I have three UITableViewCell subclasses referenced in my view controller. Two of them have UITextField's, the other has a customer UIView with a UIWebView in that. The custom UIView listens for keyboard notifications. I guess I could implement the UITextFieldDelegate in my two UITableViewCell subclasses and tell by view controller that those guys are being entered when that happens and I could have a delegate on my custom UIView to check when on keyboard notification if its for that custom UIView.